# Passing parameter to azure adf pipelines using config file by activity name

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have below config file which pass parameter to ADF pipelines according to activity number. but I want, it should pass according to activity name hence
if I reordered the pipeline I need not to reconfigure my config file beacuse then it will identify according to activity name.

```
"PL_DATA_IL_Omni_Attend": [
    {
      "name": "$.properties.start",
      "value": "2016-02-08T19:00:00Z"
    },
    {
      "name": "$.properties.end",
      "value": "2016-02-08T19:00:00Z"
    },
    {
      "name": "$.properties.activities[0].typeProperties.rootPath",
      "value": "container/realtime/"
    },
    {
      "name": "$.properties.activities[0].typeProperties.entryFilePath",
      "value": "batchprocessor.jar"
    },
    {
      "name": "$.properties.activities[0].typeProperties.className",
      "value": "com.cdp.batch.processor.XMLFilesProcessorToBlob"
    },
    {
      "name": "$.properties.activities[0].typeProperties.arguments[0]",
      "value": "dev"
    },
    {
      "name": "$.properties.activities[0].typeProperties.arguments[1]",
      "value": "Attend"
    },
    {
      "name": "$.properties.activities[0].typeProperties.arguments[2]",
      "value": "DELETE_STG"
    },
       {
      "name": "$.properties.activities[1].typeProperties.rootPath",
      "value": "container/realtime/"
    },
    {
      "name": "$.properties.activities[1].typeProperties.entryFilePath",
      "value": "batchprocessor.jar"
    },
    {
      "name": "$.properties.activities[1].typeProperties.className",
      "value": "com.processor.XMLFilesProcessorToBlob"
    },
    {
      "name": "$.properties.activities[1].typeProperties.arguments[0]",
      "value": "dev"
    },
    {
      "name": "$.properties.activities[1].typeProperties.arguments[1]",
      "value": "Attend"
    },
    {
      "name": "$.properties.activities[1].typeProperties.arguments[2]",
      "value": "READWRITE"
    },
    {
      "name": "$.properties.activities[3].typeProperties.rootPath",
      "value": "container/realtime"
    },
    {
      "name": "$.properties.activities[3].typeProperties.entryFilePath",
      "value": "batchprocessor.jar"
    },
]
```

I want something like below

```
{
          "name": "$.properties.activities[Name of the activity].typeProperties.rootPath",
          "value": "container/realtime/"
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

Sudeep, are you using ADF V1 or ADF V2? We just launched V2 of our product which allows for parameter passing.

An example of an ADF V2 pipeline with parameters here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-control-flow#create-a-data-factory

Comment: We are using ADF V1